# How to round in python when the (ndigit+1)th digit is =5?

Tags: python

Why `round(0.455, 2) = 0.46` and at the same time `round(0.155, 2)=0.15`? How the correctly round float value when the (ndigit+1)th digit is =5? I want `round(0.155, 2)=0.16`

Comment: Why should `round(0.1549999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875, 2)` be 0.16? It's clearly closer to 0.15.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: It's worth reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) when you have questions like this. This is directly addressed in the gray box.

Comment: In that case, would it be better if we use `if else` to compute the rounding?